# Why can't my Spring MVC controller mapping reference another mapping in the same controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have the following controller mapped as

```
@Controller( value = "stockToStoreController" )
@RequestMapping("/stsr")
public class StockToStoreController extends BaseController {...}
```

I have a delete mapping

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete")
public String delete(@RequestParam("xxxId") long xxxId) {

    XXXModel xxxModel = stockToStoreDao.findById(xxxId);
    if(xxxModel != null) {
        xxxDao.delete(xxxModel);
    }
    return "/stsr/requery";
}
```

That mapping looks like this

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RequestMapping(value = "/requery")
public ModelAndView requery(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("manageStockToStore");

     //do stuff

     return mav;
}
```

I try to call another mapping in the return ie., return "/stsr/requery"; I get 
the following error:

> Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: mptstp. Exception thrown : javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/stsr/requery' in servlet with name 'xxx'

Question is, do I need to explicitly define this mapping somewhere?  I do not have any MappingHandlers defined and my -servlet.xml looks like

```
    <!-- Configures the @Configuration annotation for java configuration -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.testspringmvc.stsr" />

<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Configures resources so they can be used across web modules -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/public-resources/" />

<!-- Application Message Bundle -->
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="classpath:META-INF/public-resources/mptstp-messages, classpath:META-INF/public-resources/mptstp-error-messages, classpath:META-INF/public-resources/stsr/stsr-messages" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
</bean>

<!-- Spring MVC View Resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
    <property name="basename" value="stsr-views" />
    <property name="defaultParentView" value="parentView"/>
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean id="urlConfiguredSiteIdInterceptor" class="xxx.testspringmvc.stsr.interceptor.UrlConfiguredSiteIdInterceptor">
            <property name="siteIdConfigParamName" value="urlConfiguredSiteId" />
            <property name="errorView" value="siteIdNotFound" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Any help from you guys would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

- you can redirect `return "redirect:/stsr/requery"`
- you can directly invoke the other method: `return requery(request);`

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Which is the more correct way to accomplish the redirect, relating to best practices.

Comment: depends. I'd use redirect in the common case

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for a view and you want a mapping. You have to use  a redirect:

```
return "redirect:/stsr/requery";
```